# To obtain how long a metrics has not changed?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a metrics named workqueue_depth. For example, workqueue_depth is 3 now, and i want to show how long workqueue_depth stay at 3 (such as 5min) in a table. So, I want to obtain the time by writing promql. How to write the promql???

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct it's not possible, but there are surely options that will provide the needed result:

- If *depth* takes not many values, you can change depth to be label and value of metic to be the time of last change. So at this point, you'll have also info about last time when *workqueue* has a certain depth. But you should probably change than the metric name, as it would not be syntactic anymore.
- Add another metic, like *workqueue_depth_change_seconds*, and assign to it *time_now()* each time you change *workqueue_depth*.
- Or you can make hack like this:

  max_over_time((changes(prometheus_tsdb_wal_truncations_total[15s])*time())[24h:])

  But as I said it's a hack, and at this point, it would show you last value change from last `24h`, you can always increase this `24h`, but you'll be limited to the time that you'll provide.